# UIAlertView mess up the UIWindow bounds

Tags: ios, uialertview, uiwindow

`UIAlertView` will mess up the `UIWindow` bounds, before the alert shown, the bounds is (0 0; 768 1024), after the alert shown, the bounds is (0 0; 1024 768), any idea why this is happening? Thanks a lot.

Comment: How do you say that bounds has changed?

Comment: @Akash, actually, i am using the [AGWindowView](https://github.com/hfossli/AGWindowView), the `self.window.bounds` in the `AGWindowView.m`, line 178 is giving me different result before and after the alert is shown.